# Filtering a list and the printing the 3rd value in the filtered list in Python

Tags: python, filter

This feels like a really basic thing but Ive been struggling with this for hours.

I have a list with values. I want to filter that list and on leave only the values that contain "a" in them. Then from that list I want to print the 3rd value. For some reason that I dont understand it doesnt work.

Help is appreciated!
Thank you!

`mylist = ['plane','dog','car','planet','mat']`

`mylist_words_with_a = filter(lambda word: 'a' in word, mylist)`

`third_of_mylist_with_a = mylist_words_with_a[2]`

`print(third_of_mylist_with_a)`

Comment: What does "doesnt work" mean? what does it do?

Comment: Does `third_of_mylist_with_a = list(mylist_words_with_a)[2]` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `filter` to filter the elements with 'a'. I am using here a `set` method to check inclusion. Then use `islice` to get the nth element of the `filter` generator. This enables to stop as soon as you get the element you want (imagine you have 1000 elements, there is no need to evaluate the remaining elements once you found the third that contains an a):

```
mylist = ['plane','dog','car','planet','mat']

from itertools import islice
next(islice(filter({'a'}.issubset, mylist), 2, 3))
```

output: `'planet'`

Answer (score 0):

`filter` returns an iterable. Therefore, you need to wrap the content into a list to get the filter actually executed and to access the third element by using the `[]` operator.

```
mylist = ['plane','dog','car','planet','mat']

mylist_words_with_a = filter(lambda word: 'a' in word, mylist)

third_of_mylist_with_a = list(mylist_words_with_a)[2]

print(third_of_mylist_with_a)
```

Alternatively, you can use `itertools.islice()` to avoid that the entire list is filtered and copied into an additional list. Prefer the use of iterators, if the source list is a large data set, to improve performance and to avoid unnecessary memory allocation.

```
import itertools

mylist = ['plane','dog','car','planet','mat']

mylist_words_with_a = filter(lambda word: 'a' in word, mylist)

third_of_mylist_with_a = next(itertools.islice(mylist_words_with_a, 2, 3))

print(third_of_mylist_with_a)
```